# Americano, water before the shot?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso

I was in a coffee shop the other day and noticed the barrista was pouring in the hot water before the espresso shot for my Americano. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Or [this question on the procedure for making Caffè Americano](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/402/procedure-for-making-a-caffe-americano). You got a "[long black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_black)" (adding espresso into water); [Caffè Americano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffè_Americano) is more traditionally adding water into espresso. I happen to prefer the result of long black, which helps preserve crema.

Comment: Looks like @Stephie's comment was auto-deleted... she had linked [this question about cooling espresso before adding to a drink](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/164/when-making-a-long-black-how-long-should-hot-water-cool-before-adding-espresso), and there is also more description of [end result](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/end-result-of-americano-vs-long-black).